# Latex Pseudocode missing number cannot resolve

Tags: algorithms, pseudocode, algpseudocode

```
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{LexBFS Algorithm}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\Function{LexBFS}{$G=(V, E)$}
\State Let $P$ be an empty list \Comment{Initialize the permutation}
\State Let $Q$ be an empty queue \Comment{Initialize the queue}
\For{each vertex $v \in V$}
\State Mark $v$ as not visited
\EndFor

    \For{each vertex $v \in V$}
        \If{$v$ is not visited}
            \State \Call{BFS}{$v, P, Q$} \Comment{Call BFS from unvisited vertices}
        \EndIf
    \EndFor

    \State \textbf{return} $P$ \Comment{Return the lexicographic BFS ordering}
\EndFunction

\Function{BFS}{$s, P, Q$}
    \State Mark $s$ as visited
    \State Enqueue $s$ to $Q$
    
    \While{$Q$ is not empty}
        \State Dequeue $u$ from $Q$
        \State Append $u$ to $P$

        \For{each neighbor $v$ of $u$}
            \If{$v$ is not visited}
                \State Mark $v$ as visited
                \State Enqueue $v$ to $Q$
            \EndIf
        \EndFor
    \EndWhile
\EndFunction
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
```

All the `\EndFor` are returning error "missing number, treated as zero" and all the `\If` is returning error "Argument of \algocf@Ifstrip has an extra". I cannot figure out what I did wrong. My package used are
`\usepackage{algorithm} \usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}`

Comment: please always make the example a complete small document that shows the error

Comment: You're probably also loading `\usepackage{algorithm2e}`. Don't do that. Remove it from your preamble and try compiling again.

Comment: I'm not loading algorithm2e though

Comment: If your example was complete from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}` and gave the error we would not have to guess the cause, we could trace tex and see the problem.